# how to use the css in jspdf through jquery

Tags: jquery, css, laravel

I have used the `jspdf` with multiple table but can't set that multiple pages in same manner and not implement any css in jquery.

```
function savepdf()
{
    $('link[href="{{ asset('assets/admin/pages/css/profile.css')}}"]');
    $('.first').addClass("col-md-12");

    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "letter");

    doc.addHTML(document.getElementById('example'), 10, 10,
    {
        pagesplit: true, 
        margin: { 
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60, 
            left: 40,
            width: 595.28,
            useFor: 'cmd'
        }
    },
    function () 
    {
        doc.save("test.pdf")
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for better understanding.